# How to teleport a player who activates a command block without using @p?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Using command blocks, how can I make the person that touched the command block's button get teleported, not the person closest to the command block?

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible. The closest you can get is by specifying that it should teleport the player closest to the button, like this:

```
/tp @p[x=buttonX,y=buttonY,z=buttonZ] newLocationX newLocationY newLocationZ
```

e.g.:

```
/tp @p[x=420,y=42,z=-1337] 1024 37 2000001
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing about command blocks is that they are operated by *redstone signals*, which can vary from circuts as small as a single button to circuts as huge and sprawling as mob farms to complex circuts like self-powered timers. Redstone signals do not carry identity (they may not even have it), so there isn't a way to tell who pushed a button.

[The Guy With the Hat's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/248524/133336) is good to use - teleport the player closest to the structure. You will likely get more perfect mileage if you use a pressure plate on top of the block instead of a button, and then you can use a radius limiter on the @p (I think it's `r=1` or whatever other number) to ensure that some random player won't get teleported when a mob presses the button.